# Gradient Descent Problem with smallest/simplest data on planet Earth

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I want to implement the Gradient Descent Algorithm on this simple data but I am facing problems. It would be great if someone points me in the right direction. The answer should be 7 for x=6 but I'm not getting there.

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
m_gradient = 0
b_gradient = 0
m, b = 0, 0
learning_rate = 0.1

N = len(Y)
for p in range(100):
    for idx in range(len(Y)):
        x = X[idx]
        y = Y[idx]
        hyp = (m * x) + b
        m_gradient += -(2/N) * x * (y - hyp)
        b_gradient += -(2/N) * (y - hyp)
    m = m - (m_gradient * learning_rate)
    b = b - (b_gradient * learning_rate)
print(b+m*6)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like gradient descent to me. If you want 7 for `x=6` then you're doing "extrapolation". Gradient descent is used to find the minimum of a function.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the problem values at the point of divergence and trace them back to their sources.

Comment: @Kris gradient descent is a valid description here.  It is not at odds with extrapolation.

Comment: @Prune My bad! I see this is trying to find a line of best fit using gradient descent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want coefficients for Linear Regression using Gradient Descent. Some more data points, a slightly smaller learning rate, training for more epochs by looking at the loss will help reduce error.

As input size gets larger the code below will give slightly off results. The above mentioned methods such as training for more epoch will give correct results for larger range of numbers.

#### Vectorized Version

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
Y = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
w_gradient = 0
b_gradient = 0
w, b = 0.5, 0.5

learning_rate = .01
loss = 0
EPOCHS = 2000
N = len(Y)


for i in range(EPOCHS):

    # Predict
    Y_pred = (w * X) + b

    # Loss
    loss = np.square(Y_pred - Y).sum() / (2.0 * N)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(loss)

    # Backprop
    grad_y_pred = (2 / N) * (Y_pred - Y)
    w_gradient = (grad_y_pred * X).sum()
    b_gradient = (grad_y_pred).sum()

    # Optimize
    w -= (w_gradient * learning_rate)
    b -= (b_gradient * learning_rate)

print("\n\n")
print("LEARNED:")
print(w, b)
print("\n")
print("TEST:")
print(np.round(b + w * (-2)))
print(np.round(b + w * 0))
print(np.round(b + w * 1))
print(np.round(b + w * 6))
print(np.round(b + w * 3000))

# Expected: 30001, but gives 30002.
# Training for 3000 epochs will give expected result.
# For simple demo with less training data and small input range 2000 in enough
print(np.round(b + w * 30000))
```

**Output**

```
LEARNED:
1.0000349103409163 0.9998271260509328

TEST:
-1.0
1.0
2.0
7.0
3001.0
30002.0
```

#### Loop Version

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
Y = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
w_gradient = 0
b_gradient = 0
w, b = 0.5, 0.5

learning_rate = .01
loss = 0
EPOCHS = 2000
N = len(Y)


for i in range(EPOCHS):

    w_gradient = 0
    b_gradient = 0
    loss = 0

    for j in range(N):

        # Predict
        Y_pred = (w * X[j]) + b

        # Loss
        loss += np.square(Y_pred - Y[j]) / (2.0 * N)

        # Backprop
        grad_y_pred = (2 / N) * (Y_pred - Y[j])
        w_gradient += (grad_y_pred * X[j])
        b_gradient += (grad_y_pred)

    # Optimize
    w -= (w_gradient * learning_rate)
    b -= (b_gradient * learning_rate)

    # Print loss
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(loss)


print("\n\n")
print("LEARNED:")
print(w, b)
print("\n")
print("TEST:")
print(np.round(b + w * (-2)))
print(np.round(b + w * 0))
print(np.round(b + w * 1))
print(np.round(b + w * 6))
print(np.round(b + w * 3000))

# Expected: 30001, but gives 30002.
# Training for 3000 epochs will give expected result.
# For simple demo with less training data and small input range 2000 in enough
print(np.round(b + w * 30000))
```

**Output**

```
LEARNED:
1.0000349103409163 0.9998271260509328

TEST:
-1.0
1.0
2.0
7.0
3001.0
30002.0
```

Comment: Now I can see the problem with my code. I don't know why I shouldn't comment "Thanks" here as you guys really helped me to find the error in my code.

Comment: If these answers helped then please mark one of these as accepted so others can find it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the gradients incorrectly for all but the first iteration. You need to set both gradients to 0 in the outer `for` loop.

```py
X = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
m_gradient = 0
b_gradient = 0
m, b = 0, 0
learning_rate = 0.1

N = len(Y)
for p in range(100):
    for idx in range(len(Y)):
        x = X[idx]
        y = Y[idx]
        hyp = (m * x) + b
        m_gradient += -(2/N) * x * (y - hyp)
        b_gradient += -(2/N) * (y - hyp)
    m = m - (m_gradient * learning_rate)
    b = b - (b_gradient * learning_rate)
    m_gradient, b_gradient = 0, 0

print(b+m*6)
```

For example consider `b_gradient`. Before first iteration `b_gradient = 0` and is calculated as `0 + -0.5*(y0 - (m*x0 +b)) + -0.5(y1 - (m*x1 +b)) + -0.5(y2 - (m*x2 + b)) + -0.5(y3 - (m*x3 + b))`, where x0 and y0 are `X[0]` and `Y[0]`, respectively.

After the first iteration the value of `b_gradient` is -7, this is correct.

The problem starts with the second iteration. Instead of calculating `b_gradient` as the sum of `(-0.5(yn - (m*xn + b))` for 0 <= n <= 3, you calculated it as the previous value of `b_gradient` plus the sum of `(-0.5(yn - (m*xn + b))` for 0 <= n <= 3.

After the second iteration the value of `b_gradient` is -2.6, this is incorrect. The correct value is 4.4, note that `4.4 - 7 = -2.6`.